# c# code for getting xml elements

Tags: c#, xml

I have following xml file:

```
<os:tax>
     <os:cat name="abc" id="1">
         <os:subcat name="bcd" id="11">
             <os:t name="def" id="111">
                 <os:cut name="hello" id="161" cutURL="/abc/a.html"/>
                 <os:cut name="hello2" id="162" cutURL="/abc1/a1.html"/>
                 <os:cut name="hello3" id="163" cutURL="/abc4/a3.html"/>
             </os:t>
         </os:subcat>
     </os:cat>
     <os:cat name="def" id="2">
         <os:subcat name="bcd" id="22">
             <os:t name="def" id="222">
                 <os:cut name="hello" id="171" cutURL="/abcs/a.html"/>
                 <os:cut name="hello2" id="172" cutURL="/abcs1/a1.html"/>
                 <os:cut name="hello3" id="173" cutURL="/abcs4/a3.html"/>
             </os:t>
         </os:subcat>
     </os:cat>
 </os:tax>
```

Its a bigger file with lot of os:cat under it. I need to get string value for:
os:cat -> id , name
os:subcat -> id, name
os: t -> id, name
os: cut -> id, name, cutURL

I have this so far:

```
XmlNodeList tax = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("os:tax");
foreach (XmlNode node in tax)
{
    XmlElement cat = (XmlElement)node;
    // than get string values here?
}
```

Is this correct? Can anyone show me efficient way to do this? Or right way to do this easily?

Comment: Can you use .NET 3.5 or higher? LINQ to XML makes this simpler...

Comment: @Jon i am using .NET 3.5 but i have never used LINQ. Can you explain me how to do it?

Comment: @Henk - structure is correct for xml file. As per the result i want id of each cat and there name, then get id of subcat its name, then get cut name, id and url, so probablly a loop to get all that.

Comment: @Gurnor, google for some LINQ to XML samples.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Saving xml data in Oracle in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8187136/saving-xml-data-in-oracle-in-c-sharp).  Asked 32 minutes before this one was.

Comment: @Gurnor, but how should the result look like? Should it be in some structure of classes? Or do you want something like `foreach` for each level of the structure?

Comment: you should look into a tool called linqpad... it lets you try the code for these kinds of things on the fly

Comment: @svick i want to finally save all these values in the oracle table.

Comment: @svick- can you please show me just how you will write code for above example? I will also search for the examples of linq online. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a sample for LINQ to XML - but I *strongly* suggest you look for full LINQ to XML tutorials. (And get to grips with the rest of LINQ...)

(EDIT: I hadn't spotted the `t` part before.)

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("tax.xml");
XNamespace os = "http://something"; // You haven't included the declaration...

foreach (XElement cat in doc.Descendants(os + "cat"))
{
    int catId = (int) cat.Attribute("id");
    string catName = (string) cat.Attribute("name");

    foreach (XElement subcat in cat.Elements(os + "subcat"))
    {
        int subId = (int) subcat.Attribute("id");
        string subName = (string) subcat.Attribute("name");

        foreach (XElement t in subcat.Elements(os + "t"))
        {
            int tId = (int) t.Attribute("id");
            string tName = (string) t.Attribute("name");
            foreach (XElement cut in t.Elements(os + "cut"))
            {
                string cutId = (int) cut.Attribute("id");
                string cutName = (string) cut.Attribute("name");
                string cutUrl = (string) cut.Attribute("cutURL");
                // Use the variables here
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This assumes there's only one subcat for each cat - I don't know if that's correct.

You *may* want to express this as a LINQ query instead... it depends on what you need to do.

Here's a LINQ query version - having looked at everything you're using, I think this makes more sense:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("tax.xml");
XNamespace os = "http://something"; // You haven't included the declaration...

var query = from cat in doc.Descendants(os + "cat")
            from subcat in cat.Elements(os + "subcat")
            from t in subcat.Elements(os + "t")
            from cut in t.Elements(os + "cut")
            select new
            {
                CatId = (int) cat.Attribute("id"),
                CatName = (string) cat.Attribute("name"),
                SubCatId = (int) subcat.Attribute("id"),
                SubCatName = (string) subcat.Attribute("name"),
                TId = (int) t.Attribute("id"),
                TName = (string) t.Attribute("name"),
                CutId = (int) cut.Attribute("id")
                CutName = (string) cut.Attribute("name")
                CutUrl = (string) cut.Attribute("cutURL")
            };
```

Note that I've converted all the ID values to `int` rather than `string`. You could convert them to strings instead, of course, but if they *are* all integers, it makes sense to parse them as such.

Comment: sorry forgot to mention it could have more than one subcat

Comment: @Gurnor: Will edit, but without knowing much more about what you need to do with them, it's somewhat hard to really give much concrete help. You should really find a LINQ to XML tutorial.

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but it seems like there should be an easier way. Can't LINQ to XML traverse the document? Couldn't you just do: `doc.Descendants(os + "cut")`?

Comment: @JamesJohnson: You could indeed - but then you'd still need to get the *parent* elements for their attributes. It's easy enough to do, certainly. Does the second part of the answer look more friendly to you?

Comment: @JonSkeet: Second part definitely looks friendlier. I think it just looks more complicated than I'm used to because you're grabbing the attribute values at each level. LINQ query definitely looks a lot cleaner, though :)

Comment: @Jon - Quick question. So what linq does is get all elements without even using foreach loop?

Comment: @JonSkeet- Sorry to keep on disturbing you. But if i want to save all these values in database. Can i do that inside LINQ Query? Or will i have to save each element individually?

Comment: @Gurnor: You'd probably want to iterate over the results, saving them to the database either once per result or as a batch. It wouldn't be part of the LINQ query itself.

Comment: @JonSkeet- so something like foreach loop on query? Like foreach(query q) {// add values to database}??

Comment: @Gurnor: Well, `foreach (var result in query) { ... }`

Comment: @JonSkeet - I tried this:  foreach (var x in query)
            {
                foreach (var catId in cat )
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(catId);
                    Console.ReadLine();
                }
            
            }              //Does not seem to work?? Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: @Gurnor: Yes, you should be using `x.CatId`, `x.CatName`, `x.SubCatId` etc. You'll get one result like this for each `cut`.

Comment: @JonSkeet - Very sorry to keep on bugging you. But when i got all this and it works fine but there is one problem if there are more than one subcat it just picks last one and leave all the ones before that? For that do i need to change the query? Or how i am displaying result? Again i appreciate your help a lot. Thanks very very much.

Comment: @Gurnor: No, the code I've given should be picking out *all* the results. It may well be how you're dealing with the results. Or maybe there are no `t` or `cut` elements under some of the subcats.

Answer (score 2):

Jon's suggestion to use LINQ to XML is the way to go, but I've included the old way below. My XPath is a little (very) rusty, so forgive me if there are any mistakes:

```
var doc = new XmlDocument(); //your document

var xmlnsManager = new System.Xml.XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
xmlnsManager.AddNamespace("os", "http://bla");

foreach (XmlNode node in doc.SelectNodes("//os:subcat/os:t/os:cut", xmlnsManager))
{
    string value = node.Attributes.GetNamedItem("name").Value;
}
```

See this article if you need more help: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/318545

Answer (score 0):

Consider using `XElement` along with `Lambda` expression.

```
XNamespace osNs = "http://xml.com"; // Like Jon said, you haven't included the namespace url

XElement taxElement = XElement.Load("path/to/your/xml/file");


foreach(var cat in taxElement.Decendents(osNs + "cat"))
{
    Console.WriteLine(cat.Attribute("id").Value);

    foreach(var subcat in cat.Decendents(osNs + "subcat"))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(subcat.Attribute("id").Value);

        foreach(var t in subcat.Decendents(osNs + "t"))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(t.Attribute("id").Value);

            foreach(var cut in t.Decendents(osNs + "cut"))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(cut.Attribute("id").Value);
                Console.WriteLine(cut.Attribute("name").Value);
                Console.WriteLine(cut.Attribute("cutURL").Value);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It's just capturing one node at by another. If you want to get all the **curURL** then you can just write something like this:

foreach(var cut in taxElement.Decendents(osNs + "cut"))
   {
      Console.WriteLine(cut.Attribute("cutURL"));
   }

Even you can use Lambda like if you want something like all `os:cut` where `os:subcat` `id = 22`

```
taxElement.Decendents("osNs + "subcat").Where(p => p.Attribute("id").Value == "22").Decendents(osNs + "cut");
```

Please go through some tutorial on LINQ to XML or something on XElement.

Hope this helps!